# Pandas - Find increasing trend in a row of different columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataset of milk production in India. I am trying to get the list of 5 states(if present) in which the total Milk Production increased in last 3 years through Pandas.

```
State        Total10-11 Total11-12  Total13-14  Total14-15  Total15-16
Andhra Pradesh    11204      12088       13007         9656      10817
Arunachal Pradesh    28         22          43           46         50
Assam               790        797         814          829        844
Bihar              6517       6643        7197         7775       8289
Chhattisgarh       1030       1118        1208         1232       1278
Goa                  60         60          68           66         54
Gujarat            9322       4089       11112        11690      12262
Haryana            6268       6661        7442         7902       8381
Himachal Pradesh   1102       1120        1151         1173       1283
```

Expected output:

```
State
Assam
Bihar
Chhattisgarh
Haryana
Himachal Pradesh
```

I want to find the states which have an increasing trend in their milk production each year. The Milk production should not have decreased in the consequent years compared to the previous years. the expected output states have the production in increasing order and there is no dip even once in their production. I am kind of stuck with this one, I tried a few methods but they are not close to the right answer. What's the solution ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your effort, and what is the output you are expecting for more clairty.

Comment: What do you mean by increasing trend here?

Comment: I mean if the total milk production is increasing each year(without decreasing in the consequent years). eg: As in Arunachal Pradesh, Assam the milk production is increasing each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the difference is always increasing you can use `diff > 0` and `cumsum` i.e

```
df = df.set_index("State/UT Name")

temp = (df.T.diff() > 0).cumsum()
# Values will increment if the difference between past and present is positive 
State/UT Name  Andhra Pradesh  Arunachal Pradesh  Assam  Bihar  Chhattisgarh  \
Total10-11                  0                  0      0      0             0   
Total11-12                  1                  0      1      1             1   
Total13-14                  2                  1      2      2             2   
Total14-15                  2                  2      3      3             3   
Total15-16                  3                  3      4      4             4   

State/UT Name  Goa  Gujarat  Haryana  Himachal Pradesh  
Total10-11       0        0        0                 0  
Total11-12       0        0        1                 1  
Total13-14       1        1        2                 2  
Total14-15       1        2        3                 3  
Total15-16       1        3        4                 4  

# The one with max sum is the one that kept increasing over time 
temp.sum().nlargest(10)

State/UT Name
Assam                10
Bihar                10
Chhattisgarh         10
Haryana              10
Himachal Pradesh     10
Andhra Pradesh        8
Arunachal Pradesh     6
Gujarat               6
Goa                   3
```

If you want the state names then

```
states = temp.sum().nlargest(5).index.tolist()

['Assam', 'Bihar', 'Chhattisgarh', 'Haryana', 'Himachal_Pradesh']
```

Comment: Apparently, I am looking for state names where there is no decrease in production in a single year and just goes on increasing compared to it's previous years.

Comment: Index is your state names

Comment: @SrinidhiPatil check the edit hope you understand what I did. This is my approach. There might be better ones

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking for a trend, then I think visualization is the answer.

You could do something like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = df.set_index('state')
df.T.plot(figsize=(10,15))
```

[image]

Or to look at them individually:

```
df.T.plot(figsize=(15,20), subplots=True,layout=(3,3))
```

[image]